# css colored list item makes the text untidy

Tags: html, css

I'm styling the color of a list of items by using CSS like this

```css
.bullet {
  list-style: none;
}

.bullet li::before {
  content: "\2022";
  color: #11AAE2;
  margin-right: 12px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="bullet">
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut e</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad </li>
</ul>
```

The list bullet color changed but the problem is if the text is long, it shows like this picture below. I'm sorry I don't know how to explain this situation using English. I want all the text to start at the red line. What should I do?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add text- indent on your .bullet

```
.bullet {
    list-style: none;
    text-indent: -1em;
  }
```

it will fix it

Comment: well, it works! although it's not very neat but thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution.

```css
.bullet {
    list-style: none;
}

.bullet li {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.bullet li::before {
    content: "\2022";
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 0;
    color: #11AAE2;
    margin-right: 12px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="bullet">
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut e</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad </li>
</ul>
```